# Missing Google Analytics conversions for PayPal Website Payments Standard orders

Tags: google-analytics, paypal-standard, ecommerce-tracking

I'm pulling my hair out here, I've done a lot of searching and can't find an answer:

Using CE 1.7.0.2, whenever a customer pays using PayPal Website Payments Standard and exits PayPal before the redirect takes them back to the Onepage Success page the conversion / eCommerce referral data isn't showing in Google Analytics. The PayPal payment data makes it back to Magento OK, as the order status gets updated OK, it's just GA that is missing the data.

I realise using PayPal Payflow or another onsite gateway will get around this issue, but surely there must be a fix for PayPal Website Payments Standard?

Any ideas?

Comment: This is still a problem in CE 1.9.2 , most eCommerce solutions also have the same problem, but they are typically solved by redirecting to a utmnoreferal in the PayPal/Portal settings. Unfortunately, the settings are overwritten in the PayPal Module, which means the fix will involve a small edit to the PayPal module, or getting the referral data from the massive visitor log in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm really trying to find a solution for the last days as well. First of all there is a paid extension that is getting the data from the admin backend. Then there is a free one, but it is not working the way it is supposed to be for me (https://github.com/magento-hackathon/UniversalGaConversionTracking)

And then there is a very short article on how to set it up manually (http://daniel-koch.net/magento-order-mit-google-analytics-tracken/) In german language.

Answer (score 0):

You should add paypal.com to your referral exclusion list on Google Analytics

Go to your Admin Google Analytics => Property => Tracking info => referral exclusion list

Comment: This method removes conversions that come from PayPal... which is not what most people need. I suspect the real solution will come as a mod to the PayPal module, as it seems to override many PayPal.com settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I recently had to manage this functionality for a customer using Magento CE 1.9. Perhaps it can be useful to someone else.

The flow is that:
 - priority to Google Analytics / Google Tag Manager conversion triggers
 - if thanks page is not loaded/reached/javascripts are disabled, the extension sends data with Google Measurement Protocol
 - to avoid a double conversion, it uses a mismatch in two queues (we don't want to send data if the conversion is already registered)
 - to ensure source ascription, it saves the visitor's referral, utms, etc. in a cookie